# Get closest Entity from the Player on a 2D battlefield

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity3d

I am building a little game in using Unity, and recently made an algorithm to get the closest `Entity` to the player on the battlefield. I made a working sample in [RexTester](http://rextester.com/ZRUE17732) (it is not the real code, but the algorithm is exactly the same).

I am interested in the `GetCloserEntityFromPlayer` function. Basically, it loops through all the entities and find the closest one. The function is defined as below:

```
public static Entity GetCloserEntityFromPlayer(){
    List<Entity> temp = new List<Entity>();
    temp.AddRange(allies);
    temp.AddRange(enemies);

    //assume the first is the closest, and compare to the others
    Entity aux = temp[0];
    int distance = Math.Abs((aux.X + aux.Y) - (player.X + player.Y));

    for(int i = 1; i < temp.Count; i++)
    {
        //in my game, the distance is the absolute difference 
        //between the sum of both Entities x and y values
        int temp_distance = Math.Abs((temp[i].X + temp[i].Y) - (player.X + player.Y));
        if(temp_distance < distance)
        {
            aux = temp[i];                    
        }
    }
    return aux;
}
```

When the `Entity` number starts growing, the game seems to get a little slow, with FPS dropping. I was thinking of maintaining the Entities list ordered, so I would help the branch predictor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this function would be more idiomatic using a `foreach` loop:

```
Entity closest = null;
int distance = int.MaxValue;

for (var other in entities)
{
    int d = Math.Abs((other.X + other.Y) - (player.X + player.Y));
    if(d < distance)
    {
        closest = other;
    }
}
return closest;
```

> When the Entity number starts growing, the game seems to get a little slow, with FPS drop. I was thinking of maintaining the Entities list ordered, so I would help the branch predictor, I don't know...

If you can keep entities sorted by their `e.X + e.Y` value,
then you could significantly speed up the search using binary search:
you will be able to find the position of the player in the list,
and check only its two neighbors to find the closest.

However, keeping the entities sorted might be costly as well.
I don't know if that's the case here,
it depends on the rest of your application that you did not include in the post.
My guess is that it's going to be so costly that you will not gain any benefit at all.

On the other hand,
if you need to find the closest entity for not only one player,
but multiple entities,
and if you perform that step for all entities at once,
then you will benefit from performing the sort right before you look for the closest neighbors.
This is different from keeping the entities sorted at all times.
You would only sort right before it's needed.

Comment: Thank you! I will test the performance with the entities ordered, and will change it to a Foreach loop

Comment: In the case of Unity3d, it's best to not use `foreach`, due to a bug in the implementation of Mono that's used. See [this](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RobertZubek/20150504/242572/C_memory_and_performance_tips_for_Unity.php).

Answer (score 1):

#### Bug

Your code isn't producing the correct results, if the goal is to get the smallest distance possible. This is because of these lines of code:

```
int temp_distance = Math.Abs((temp[i].X + temp[i].Y) - (player.X + player.Y));
if(temp_distance < distance)
{
    aux = temp[i];                    
}
```

If we assume that `distance == 100` and for the first time the `if` statement returns true let's say `temp_distance == 20`, then on the next iteration `temp_distance == 50` the `if` still evaluates to `true` and `aux` becomes `temp[i]` but isn't the closest entity.

To overcome this problem you would need to assign `temp_distance` to `distance` inside the `if` like so

```
int temp_distance = Math.Abs((temp[i].X + temp[i].Y) - (player.X + player.Y));
if(temp_distance < distance)
{
    aux = temp[i];       
    distance = temp_distance;             
}
```

---

This

```
List<Entity> temp = new List<Entity>();
```

could use a better name. Why don't you call it `entities` ?

While we are at naming, variables should be named using `camelCase` instead of `Snake_case` casing, hence `temp_distance` should be either named `tempDistance` or `currentDistance`.

---

If the right hand side makes the type obvious one should use the `var` type like

```
var entities = new List<Entity>();
```

---

Using a foreach loop like @janos suggested is the way to go. Precalculating the `players` `X` and `Y` should be done as well because they won't change.

All together would lead to

```
public static Entity GetCloserEntityFromPlayer(){

    var entities = new List<Entity>();
    entities.AddRange(allies);
    entities.AddRange(enemies);

    Entity closestEntity = null;
    int playersXY = player.X + player.Y;
    int distance = int.MaxValue;

    foreach(var entity in entities)
    {
        //in my game, the distance is the absolute difference 
        //between the sum of both Entities x and y values
        int currentDistance = Math.Abs(temp[i].X + temp[i].Y - playersXY);
        if(currentDistance < distance)
        {
            closestEntity = entity;                    
            distance = currentDistance;
        }
    }
    return closestEntity;
}
```

Comment: I will review the variable names, and thanks for the bugfix"

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give you the best possible solution with your current system.
If you find you need more performance, especially when you have a lot of entities, you'll need to look into spatial partitioning or spatial hashing.

Your big bottleneck at the moment is that you have no way to "intelligently" check your set of entities. Partitioning gives you ways to include or exclude entities in your search. So now your check is bounded rather than o(n).

The basic idea is that you checking the most relevant information first, and if you get a result you don't have to check anything else.

This can be something more complex (like a quad-tree) or something relatively simple (a grid system).